# I have a problem when I try to do migration

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, migration

Hello I have a project in symfony and I need to do migrations to create tables correctly to the database.

```
php bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate
```

When I run this command to migrate I get en error as

```
An exception occurred in the driver: could not find driver
```

how can I fix it?

Comment: Have you set your database url in your .env file?

Comment: I do know this issue. Check your database URL in your .env file. If you have a version number in it, check if it match your mariadb/mysql version. Otherwise adapt it or remove it.